# Mongoose - How to find by an 'array' of ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting an array of `ObjectId` from a query, then I need to use them inside another query.

Here is the function:

```
exports.getAllByShop = wrap(async(req, res, next) => {
    const products = await Product.find({ _shop: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.shopId) }).select('_id');
    // how to make this query?
    const sales = await Sale.find({ _product: { $in: [ products ]}});
    res.status(200).json(sales);
});
```

The result of the first query `products` looks like this:

```
[ 
  { _id: 5be3601f90e40b35547ae6b4 },
  { _id: 5be4b5a3443abf196cb4cc9a }
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
const sales = await Sale.find({ _product: { 
$in: 
  [ 
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(prod1),
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(prod2),
    ... 
  ]
}});
```

I need to find all the `sales` that have their `_product` equals to the values of the above array. Right now it doesn't work and show this message: `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[ { _id: 5be3601f90e40b35547ae6b4 },↵  { _id: 5be4b5a3443abf196cb4cc9a } ]" at path "_product" for model "sale""`. How to make this last query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre inserting an array, into an array, try this instead

```
const productIds = products.map((v) => v)
const sales = await Sale.find({ _product: { $in: productIds }});
```

Comment: Still the same result for the array. How to transform `[ { _id: xxx }, { _id: yyy } ]`  into this `[ 
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(xxx),
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(yyy) 
  ]`?

Comment: mongoose should know the type based on the schema so you should not need to cast them. but if you wanted to try just add them to the map like `products.map((v) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(v))`

Comment: You're right. Got it working by taking off the extra `[ ]`

Comment: one last question... `_product` is declared this way in the schema: `_product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'product' }`. Can I recover the `ref` just by using `populate` like this: `const sales = await Sale.find({ _product: { $in: productIds }}).populate('product');` ?

Comment: was going to mention populate originally, Yes you can use `populate('_product')` and mongo will return those documents as well. populate() takes the field name not the model name